# Nagios + check_http with header data

Tags: linux, nagios, curl, cookie

With cURL, I can successfully log into the website I want have Nagios test by passing --cookies.

Something like this: curl --cookie "user=4reqrerqwr;userlogin=123adsfjlk324" http://mysite.com/home/index.aspx -v | grep Welcome

I know it is successful because, 1, I can visually see the rendered code and 2, the grep search for Welcome would only be seen if the authentication was successful.

I am trying to mimic this in Nagios with check_http like so:

```
./check_http -H mysite.com -u http://mysite.com/home/index.aspx -f follow 
       -s Welcome -k 'Cookie: user=4reqrerqwr;userlogin=123adsfjlk324' -v
```

One big difference I see is that in cURL the cookie is set on 1 line but the verbose response from check_http shows the cookie on two lines.

```
Cookie: user=4reqrerqwr;userlogin=123adsfjlk324
```

vs.

```
Cookie: user=4reqrerqwr  
userlogin=123adsfjlk324
```

I am open to suggestions and of course alternatives. I have checked out WebInject but this seems to be SO close I hate to drop it.

Lastly, I have tried check_curl, and extended it to support cookies. This DOES work but I am getting (null) on the responses and the grep never causes Nagios to fail regardless of a valid result being returned.

Comment: Does the -a flag work for the credentials?

Comment: Those cookie values are not credentials, but rather stored cookies AFTER a successful login.

Answer (score 2):

Try passing

```
check_http ...  -k "Cookie: user=4reqrerqwr" -k "Cookie: userlogin=123adsfjlk324"
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried that too, but still get the cookie spread over two lines.

Cookie: user=4reqrerqwr  
userlogin=123adsfjlk324

Comment: I do believe I have tried -k "Cookie: user=4reqrerqwr" -k "Cookie: userlogin=123adsfjlk324" as well, but I will try again just in case. Cheers.

Comment: The second Cookie: does not make it..

Comment: It looks like Nagios sees the ; as the start of a comment so ignore anything after that. I tried to variablize the entire comment string in a user macro but I always get the same result. It looks like a bug in Nagios.

Comment: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=328984